# Not able to add users from csv file in to Remote desktop Users group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, sccm, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I am able to import .csv file and its working for me without any error, but not able to add the users in Remote Desktop Users list. Can any one know the solution.

```
Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Intune.Autopilot.Poc\Downloads\employees.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $_.'userPrincipalName'
}
```

my csv file contains only userPrinicipalName
user@domain.com
advance thanks for helping.

please help me to get the issue resolved.

Comment: What does it mean "*not able to add the users in Remote Desktop Users list*"? And BTW: Since `Add-LocalGroupMember` takes an array of members you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: Why did you add the tags `[azure-active-directory]`, `[sccm]`,`[intune]` and `[microsoft-graph-intune]`?

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation for the `Add-LocalGroupMember` cmdlet (https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember)? According to examples provided in the article, use `-Member "CONTOSO\Administrator"` format instead of UserPrincipalName

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to import .csv file and its working for me without any error, but not able to add the users in Remote Desktop Users list. Can any one know the solution.

If you are trying to add users to the **Remote Desktop Users** group using **PowerShell** and a **CSV** file.

Make sure that  **CSV** file is properly formatted and that the column header for **userPrincipalName** is spelled correctly and also there are no extra spaces or special characters in the values.

Here is the updated code to add users to the **Remote Desktop Users**

**Excel Format:**

[image]

```
    Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\v-vallepuv\Desktop\RDP Users.csv" | ForEach-Object {
        $userPrincipalName = $_.'userPrincipalName'
        Write-Host "Adding $userPrincipalName to Remote Desktop Users group"
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $userPrincipalName
    }
```

By adding `Write-Host` statements, you can see the progress of the script and identify any issues.

**Output:**

[image]

Reference: [Add-LocalGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: There's no loop needed. `Add-LocalGroupMember` takes an array of members!!! ;-)

Comment: Hi @Olaf, yes, we can run the command from an Array as well. I just provided a user query by adding the 'Write-Host' command to monitor the script's progress. However, if I add the 'Write-Host' command without a loop to track the script's progress, the output will have a different format, like [this](https://i.imgur.com/97jEadQ.png).